# Use Lambda code for an Alexa skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've created a Lambda function that can recall items from my DynamoDB table using the primary key when I test it in Lambda.

However, I want to implement this so it can be used with Alexa.

What I want to know is, how would I do my interaction model, and also do I need to add anything to my Lambda code to make it work with Alexa skill kit?

Here is the code I have:

```js
'use strict';
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dclient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var getItems = (event, context, callback)=>{
    
    dclient.get(event.params,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            callback(null,"error occurerd");
        }
        else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });
};

exports.getItems = getItems;
```

I'm very new to this so I'd appreciate if someone could break it down for me so I can learn.

Thank you

Comment: Among other things, you'll need to configure the Alexa skill as a *trigger* for the Lambda function. You can see how to do that on [this Amazon dev docs page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html#configuring-the-alexa-skills-kit-trigger). Also, you'll need to make sure your region is set to one of the Alexa-supported regions (like N. Virginia).

Comment: You have a long way to go my friend. This is like asking "I have 4 tires, can you show me how to build a car on top of it?". Take a look at this lambda code for a skill that uses DynamoDB https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/589a2d67978fa470c7cb0e8b6abb52f48f92a506/tools/TestFlow/sampleskill2/index.js